# How to filter JSON-LD object array with JSON-LD frames?

Tags: json, credentials, semantic-web, w3c, json-ld

I have been spending two days trying to do the following, without success.

I have this example JSON-LD document:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
    "https://w3c-ccg.github.io/ldp-bbs2020/context/v1",
    "https://mycontext.com/credentials/v1"
  ],
  "type": ["VerifiableCredential"],
  "issuer": "did:example:issuer",
  "issuanceDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "expirationDate": "2029-12-31T23:59:59Z",
  "credentialSubject": {
    "id": "did:example:subject",
    "type": ["ExampleCredential"],
    "values": [
      {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
      },
      {
        "a": 4,
        "b": 5,
        "c": 6
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the following JSON-LD context (hypothetically retrievable at **https://mycontext.com/credentials/v1**):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "@protected": true,

    "schema": "https://schema.org/",

    "ExampleCredential": {
      "@id": "https://mycontext.com/credentials#ExampleCredential",

      "@context": {
        "@version": 1.1,
        "@protected": true,

        "type": "@type",

        "values": "@nest",
        "a": {
          "@id": "https://mycontext.com/credentials#a",
          "@type": "schema:example_a",
          "@nest": "values"
        },
        "b": {
          "@id": "https://mycontext.com/credentials#b",
          "@type": "schema:example_b",
          "@nest": "values"
        },
        "c": {
          "@id": "https://mycontext.com/credentials#c",
          "@type": "schema:example_c",
          "@nest": "values"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I am trying to use the following JSON-LD frame to filter only the element in the credential that has the field `a` equal to `1`:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
    "https://w3c-ccg.github.io/ldp-bbs2020/context/v1",
    "https://mycontext.com/credentials/v1"
  ],
  "@explicit": true,
  "type": ["VerifiableCredential"],
  "issuer": "did:example:issuer",
  "issuanceDate": {},
  "expirationDate": {},
  "credentialSubject": {
    "id": "did:example:subject",
    "@explicit": true,
    "type": ["ExampleCredential"],
    "values": [
      {
        "a": 1,
        "b": {},
        "c": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using the [jsonld package](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js) to perform these operations, and the final result that I would like to get corresponds to the initial document, but with the `values` field filtered to only contain the first object in the list. This is just the last of the attempts, and I have tried everything from `"@container": "@set"` to `@nest`, but clearly I am missing something. What is the right way to format the context and/or the frame so that I can achieve the expected result? Aka, **what is the right way to express a relationship in a context in which the child is a list of objects of a specific type?**

Thanks!